# simple custom jquery toggle script

Tags: jquery

I am working on a simple toggle script with jquery and can't for the life of me see why this does not work. Here is the code:

```
$('span.mission').click(function(){
    if( !$('#panel').css('top') == 0 ){
        alert('hello'); 

        $('#panel').load('/includes/mission.html').animate({
            'top': 0
        }, 2500, 'easeInOutQuint');
    }else{
        alert('goodbye');
    }
});
```

What is the problem here? It only runs the first part of the conditional regardless of the top value...

Answer (score 1):

Your condition should be like

```
if($('#panel').css('top') != 0 ){
```

So it would be like

```
$('span.mission').click(function(){
    if( $('#panel').css('top') != 0 ){
        alert('hello'); 

        $('#panel').load('/includes/mission.html').animate({
            'top': 0
        }, 2500, 'easeInOutQuint');
    }else{
        alert('goodbye');
    }
});
```

And better you can use either `.on()` or `.live()` for the click events.Since `live` is deprecated in new versions better to use `.on()`